# Is it safe to use server socket(java) to create a webserver to host a basic webpage

Tags: java, webserver, serversocket, 3d-secure

I am a student and would like to webscrap a school site to get my assignments that aren't done yet. I already figured out how to webscrap the site, but I want to be able to see the information on my phone, so I used the java server socket docs to create  webserver but I don't know if it's safe to even do that. The information is not sensitive so I don't care if anyone online can see it but I am worried that I might be unwillingly setting myself up to getting hacked. I would like to know if this is stupid idea, and a better and safer alternative exist. Also if someone could give me tips on how to making if safe if that is possible.

PS. I chose to try to create a webserver instead of just buying hosting because I don't have money, so buying hosting isn't an option. thx

I have googled a lot in the past few days, including how to create a secure webserver with java etc. and also if serversockets are safe but the results are inconclusive. Most say it's better not to even attempt as security is super hard, and others say serversockts are safe.

Comment: Web servers are sort of public by design but in your case basic authentication should be adequate

Comment: A long time ago, there was a `Jetty Web Server` application on the Android phone, you can install it on your android phone, and start it, you can access the phone's local Web Server on the phone. To `avoid external access`, bind the Jetty Web Server's IP to `127.0.0.1`. Of course, you need to put the relevant web pages and image files in a specific directory of the mobile phone as the content of the web server.